Redirecting fifo to python's stdin
$ mkfifo mypipe
$ echo "hello redirection" > mypipe

$ cat < mypipe
hello redirection


I have problems when I try to do the above with python
# pyecho.py
with open("/dev/stdin", "r") as f:
    print(f.read())

$ python3 pyecho.py < mypipe

This wont exit unless I write to the pipe twice
$ echo "hello redirection" > mypipe
$ echo "hello redirection" > mypipe

However if I put python in a loop
# pyecho.py
while True:
    with open("/dev/stdin", "r") as f:
        print(f.read())

Then after the initial iteration (requiring two writes), it goes back to working as expected.

with open("/dev/stdin", "r") as f: print(f.read()) .... why would you do that instead of import sys and  then print(sys.stdin.read())

@muru That works. I thought I was the same thing. It was just code I refactored which read from a named pipe

On Linux, reopening /dev/stdin (== /proc/self/fd/0), is not the same as just reading from the already-open fd 0, nor duplicating it, as it actually opens the file anew. With a regular file, that would result in getting an fd with the seek position at the start, regardless of where it was for the stdin fd. But pipes don't have a read position, so that shouldn't be an issue... (I don't have an answer, just thinking out loud)

@ilkkachu  You cannot seek a pipe, but it does have flow control (so the writer can get way ahead of the reader). Having two descriptors referencing the same named pipe is not going to end well.

@Paul_Pedant thanks! if you do open(0) instead of open("/dev/stdin"), it works fine. I must admit it was chatGPT that wrote "/dev/stdin", and I didn't notice because I've been writing open(0) a habit from reading codegolf
